# merge a ply-file with png

Tags: texturing, uv, node-editor

i am a newbie in using blender (just change from tinkercad, sorry)
i have the problem that i can open the ply-file in blender, also export as obj, for example. And I have a png-file which seems to be very big (12.446 x 12.446 pix)I can reduce the resolution and I can open in UV-Mapping. But for me it is not possible to merge booth files. I cannot set the intricate ply-file into UV-Mapping. I have tested with nods-workflow but without success.  Maybe I make a mistake, or it is not possible in general. The target is to get a obj, mtl and png file for 3D UV printing, Maybe someone has a solution? [image]

regards carsten

Comment: Under Object Data Properties > UV Maps you can check the ply-mesh has a uv map. If not i dont realy see a way to use the texture. Were is the object from? Looks like a scan, so normaly the scanning software should have generated the texture from/to uv koordinates of the mesh...

Comment: hi. thanks for the answer. yes it is a scan. Right now I try to unwrap the file. But it seems that my PC has not enough performance for this work. the clock turns around since nearly 15 minutes. In this case I have to order the file in uv koordinates.

Comment: the workflow with scanning normally is that your scanning software gives you a already unrawped mesh and generates a texture from those uvs. generating your own uvs with another programm cant give you the original ones as the process is a different one. Especially because your texture has a lot of ultra-small islands sadly your only bet is to get that original mesh with the original uvs.